# Why modify request after request.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

Newbie question while trying to understand code created by others. Believe me I tried to understand this. Here goes..

For what reason would someone still call functions like .qs() and .json() in Request - module after we got what we need with .post() and sent the response already. They can't affect the request.post as they are called afterwards, can they?

With my skills I'm not able to understand from response module API docs (v2.22.0) what these actually do.

This is not the whole code but I tried to get the important parts here:

```
// When request comes to /getthisapge, make external query and return data in JSON format.
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/getthispage', function(req, res, next) {
    var filter = {};
    var query = {};
    filter.category = req.query.category;
    query.onBehalf = req.query.onBehalf;
    request.post(URIandoptions, function(error, response, body) {
      res.json(body.members)
    }).qs(query).json(filter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what the post function does (unnecessary to your question), you need to look at the order of execution.

```
request.post(URIandoptions, function (error, response, body){ 
    res.json(body.members) 
}) 
.qs(query)        //  ?
.json(filter);    //  ?
```

The function passed into `post()` does not get called at that specific moment. It is given to the `post()` function to do with as it pleases. This means technically that the function may never be called (depends on the api).

`qs()` and `json()` both get called upon the returning of the prior function. Usually this type of api means the following:

- call `post()`, passing in a function to be run on completion
- call `qs()` to setup the query details
- call `json()` to tell the post function how to act, which in turn executes the actual post, running the completion function after data has been retrieved.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the function passed to post() is not executed immediately. It's executed when response is received to post().

Comment: It is executed whenever the `post()` function internals decide to execute it. In your case it looks like it executes after `json()` is called, and data is received.

Comment: My last comment came a bit short. I really appreciate your answers. What I don't understand is why the actual POST request is sent when json() is called and not during call of post() already? Shouldn't request.post() be enough by itself to execute POST request to external source. Why does it wait for qs() and json() for further setup of the request?

Comment: It is up to the module creator, that's the point. If you read the module documentation, it will likely tell you. It would help if in the future you provided links to the actual module.

Comment: Understood. Module documentation: https://github.com/request/request and https://www.npmjs.com/package/request. Version specific library: https://github.com/request/request/archive/v2.22.0.zip.   Now, I had another look on the module and saw process.nextTick utilized on calling the actual function to send the request out. While I don't completely understand the details I think I'll leave this subject for now with assumption that it's safe to call json() and qs() after the post() and still have the expected results. Thank you for your help!